# XSLT 2.0 Sort by variable from another style sheet

Tags: sorting, xslt, xslt-2.0, cross-reference

I need to create XML that is sorted by numeric values I pull from another XSLT, which I use as a cross reference. 
 The below source XML (source.xml) has four alpha characters at Partner/Header/@whse.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Partner partnerId="TradingPartner1">
    <Header whse="NCCH" >
        <Contract claimNumber="00000000" />
    </Header>
    <Header whse="TXAU" >
        <Contract claimNumber="00000000" />
    </Header>
    <Header whse="LANO" >
        <Contract claimNumber="00000000" />
    </Header>
    <Header whse="MIGR">
        <Contract claimNumber="00000000" />
    </Header>
    <Header whse="TXHO">
        <Contract claimNumber="00000000" />
    </Header>
</Partner>
```

I need to cross reference the alpha characters to get the DUNS+4.
I use this XSLT (Duns_config.xslt) to get the DUNS.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template name="SHIPTODUNS">
    <xsl:param name="Whse" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$Whse = 'LANO'"><xsl:value-of select="'0044893600101'" /></xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$Whse = 'TXHO'"><xsl:value-of select="'0044893600103'" /></xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$Whse = 'TXAU'"><xsl:value-of select="'0044893600105'" /></xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$Whse = 'NCCH'"><xsl:value-of select="'0044893600214'" /></xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$Whse = 'MIGR'"><xsl:value-of select="'8949713340601'" /></xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the main XSLT (Transaction.xslt), I include the Duns_config.xslt and call SHIPTODUNS putting the data in the variable $headerDuns. 
  I then get the last three digits of the DUNS+4 and put them into the variable $varWhse and try to sort by this variable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:include href="Duns_config.xslt"/> 
    <xsl:template match="Partner">
        <Partner partnerId="{./@partnerId}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./Header" />
        </Partner>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Header">
        <xsl:variable name="headerDuns">
            <xsl:call-template name = "SHIPTODUNS">
                <xsl:with-param name="Whse" select="./@whse" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="varWhse">           
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($headerDuns, 11, 3)" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="current()">
        <xsl:sort select="$varWhse" />
        <transaction varwhse="{$varWhse}">
            <duns number="{$headerDuns}" />
        </transaction>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is not sorted by the $varWhse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Partner partnerId="TradingPartner1">
   <transaction varwhse="214">
      <duns number="0044893600214"/>
   </transaction>
   <transaction varwhse="105">
      <duns number="0044893600105"/>
   </transaction>
   <transaction varwhse="101">
      <duns number="0044893600101"/>
   </transaction>
   <transaction varwhse="601">
      <duns number="8949713340601"/>
   </transaction>
   <transaction varwhse="103">
      <duns number="0044893600103"/>
   </transaction>
</Partner>
```

I am wanting the data to come out like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Partner partnerId="TradingPartner1">
   <transaction varwhse="101">
      <duns number="0044893600101"/>
   </transaction>
   <transaction varwhse="103">
      <duns number="0044893600103"/>
   </transaction>
   <transaction varwhse="105">
      <duns number="0044893600105"/>
   </transaction>
   <transaction varwhse="214">
      <duns number="0044893600214"/>
   </transaction>
   <transaction varwhse="601">
      <duns number="8949713340601"/>
   </transaction>
</Partner>
```

Anyone see what I am doing wrong or have another way? 
This is my first post on this site. It's a lot of information and I hope it makes sense.

Comment: this is a helpful reference in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems with your code is that the `xsl:sort` in your `Header` template is not the first instruction; `xsl:sort` **has to be** the first instruction. Another problem is that the sorting appears in the `Header` template, but it would have to be applied on an upper level. To correct these mistakes, some restructuring of your templates has to be performed.

For the following solution I chose to put all of the logic into one template - with two steps:

1. Fill a variable named `mapping` with a sub-data-structure with `item` elements.
2. Iterate over that variable with a *sorted* `xsl:for-each` and output the `transaction` elements.

The result looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:include href="Duns_config.xslt"/> 

    <xsl:template match="Partner">
        <Partner partnerId="{./@partnerId}">
            <xsl:variable name="mapping">
                <xsl:for-each select="Header">
                    <xsl:variable name="headerDuns">
                        <xsl:call-template name = "SHIPTODUNS">
                            <xsl:with-param name="Whse" select="@whse" />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="varWhse">           
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring($headerDuns, 11, 3)" />
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <item>
                        <whse><xsl:value-of select="$varWhse" /></whse>
                        <duns><xsl:value-of select="$headerDuns" /></duns>
                    </item>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each select="$mapping/item">
                <xsl:sort select="whse" />        <!-- See how xsl:sort is the first instruction -->
                <transaction varwhse="{whse}">
                    <duns number="{duns}"/>
                </transaction>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Partner>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And its output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Partner partnerId="TradingPartner1">
   <transaction varwhse="101">
      <duns number="0044893600101"/>
   </transaction>
   <transaction varwhse="103">
      <duns number="0044893600103"/>
   </transaction>
   <transaction varwhse="105">
      <duns number="0044893600105"/>
   </transaction>
   <transaction varwhse="214">
      <duns number="0044893600214"/>
   </transaction>
   <transaction varwhse="601">
      <duns number="8949713340601"/>
   </transaction>
</Partner>
```

Which is as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I was able to apply this to my XSLT and get the results needed!!  I had never thought of a variable inside of a variable ... let alone two inside of one :).  This actually opens up a whole different way of thinking to solve issues I come across in the future!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Apply sorting after getting the result of `choose`. What happen is you are still generating the xml output, but you are sorting it on the `Header` item level.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:include href="Duns_config.xslt"/> 
    <xsl:template match="Partner">
        <xsl:variable name="partial">
            <PartnerTemp partnerId="{./@partnerId}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="./Header" />
            </PartnerTemp>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$partial"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="PartnerTemp">
        <Partner partnerId="{./@partnerId}">
            <xsl:perform-sort select="transaction">
                <xsl:sort select="@varwhse"/>
            </xsl:perform-sort>
        </Partner>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Header">
        <xsl:variable name="headerDuns">
            <xsl:call-template name = "SHIPTODUNS">
                <xsl:with-param name="Whse" select="./@whse" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="varWhse">           
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($headerDuns, 11, 3)" />
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:for-each select="current()">               
            <transaction varwhse="{$varWhse}">              
                <duns number="{$headerDuns}" />
            </transaction>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This solution works also! Thanks for providing another way to get the same result.